# In a real normed linear space if $||x||=||y||$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||x+ny||-||nx+y||=0$ , then the norm comes from an inner-product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

$(V,\|\cdot|)$ be a real  normed linear space such that

$\|x\|=\|y\|$ implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \|x+ny\|-\|nx+y\|=0$, then is it true that the norm comes from an

inner-product space ?

Comment: The condition doesn't hold on $l^{\infty}$ : $x= (1,0,0,\cdots)$ and $y = (\frac{1}{2} , 1 , 0,\cdots)$, both are of norm 1, but $ \|x+ny\|_{\infty} = n$ (for n >1), while $\|nx+y\|_{\infty} = n+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: [Parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law) implies that it suffices to verify the claim for two-dimensional vector spaces. For instance, what is for the real plane endowed with the norm $\|(x_1,x_2)\|=\max (|x_1|,|x_2|)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one provided the answer, I write mine. So, it seems the following.

[Parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law) implies that it suffices to verify the claim for two-dimensional vector spaces.

So, let on the plane $\Bbb R^2$ is defined a norm $\|\cdot\|$ satisfying the proposed equality. Let $K=\{x\in\Bbb R^2:\|x\|\le 1\}$ be the unit ball of the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Since the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is a continuous function, $K$ is a closed subset of the plane. Since $K$ is a bounded set, it is compact. Since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, $K$ is convex. As $\|\cdot\|$ we denote the standard norm on the plane. For each angle $\alpha\in\Bbb T=\{z\in\Bbb R^2:|z|=1\}$ put  $f(\alpha)=\sup\{\lambda>0:\lambda\alpha\in K\}$. Using the convexity and compactness of the set $K$, it is easy to check that the function $f$ is continuous.

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb T $ be arbitrary angles. Chose vectors $x,y\in\Bbb R^2$ such that 
$\arg x=\alpha$, $\arg y=\beta $, and $\|x\|=\|y\|=a$. Then $\|x\|=|x|f(\alpha)$ and $\|y\|=|y|f(\beta)$. Also for each $n$ we have $\|x+ny\|=|x+ny|f(\alpha_n)$ and $\|y+nx\|=|y+nx|f(\beta_n)$, where $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n=\alpha$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_n=\beta$. By Theorem of cosines,
$$|x+ny|=|y+nx|=a\sqrt{n^2+1-2n\cos(\alpha-\beta)}=g(n).$$

Since

$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty} \|x+ny\|-\|nx+y\|=\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)(f(\alpha_n)-f(\beta_n))$$

and $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)=\infty$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\alpha_n)-f(\beta_n)=0$. By the continuity of the function $f$,

$$f(\alpha)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\alpha_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty}f(\beta_n)=f(\beta).$$

Thus the function $f$ is constant, so the set $K$ is a standard ball, that implies the claim for the plane.

Comment: Why it suffices to prove i for only two dimensional vector spaces ?

Comment: @SaunDev Because to verify parallelogram law for each pair $x,y$ of vectors it suffices to consider only a linear subspace spanned by this pair.